# Can we do Multisignature transaction for bitcoin_cash?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, multi-signature

I tried implementing multi-signature for bitcoin and it worked successfully. Is it possible to implement multi-signature transactions for Bitcoin_Cash?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bitcoin Cash supports exactly the same script opcodes as Bitcoin (as of this writing), so multisig transactions can be created and spent in exactly the same way.

Comment: Could you give me an example to create the multisig transaction for bitcoin cash?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you are doing for Bitcoin.  It should be very easy to adapt it for Bitcoin Cash.